# How to calculate frequency of item with condition on two or more column data?

Tags: r

I have data read from csv file in R language, then I want to calculate frequency of items based on conditions on two or more columns.

```
a  aaa 12
b  bbb 2
c  ccc 10
a  aaa 23
a  abb 13
b  bcc 23
b  bbb 5
c  cbb 73
```

i want the output in below format with condition
if column 1 is equal to 'a' and column 2 is equal to 'aaa' then count for a, same for b and c.

output:

```
a 2
b 2
c 1
```

Comment: Just do `table(df1[1:2])` Or if it is only for 'aaa', then `table(df1[df1[,2]=='aaa',-3])`

Comment: Thanks, from where i can study such kind of example in r. I am a new learner to R language.